# Json ajax DatePicker - unavailable dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datepicker

I have retrieved database records of dates and filled it into a JSON Object. I am trying to send the JSON to javascript so that the DatePicker UI will be dynamic by having whatever dates that has been saved in the JSON to be unavailable on the calendar.

However, it doesn't seem to be working correctly as all dates on the calendar are unselectable .

**index.jsp**

```js
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var dates;
      $.ajax({
         url:'dating',
          type:'post',
          data: {
              action: 'unavail_dates',
              unavaildates: '2'
          },
          success: function (data) {
              dates = data;
              console.log ( dates );
          }
      });

      $('#MyDate').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          beforeShowDay: function (date) {
              var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
              return [dates != undefined && $.inArray(string, dates) > -1];
          },
          onSelect: function (dateText) {
              jQuery(this).change();
          }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>Select appointment date: </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="MyDate" value="" /></td>
  </tr> 
</body>
</html>
```

**dating.java**

```js
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import object.Dates;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class dating
 */
public class dating extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public dating() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  Connection con = null;
     Statement st = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     String dbName = "eBooking";
     String uname = "user";
     String pwd = "user";
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName;


     try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pwd);
       System.out.println("Connection Established: " + con);
       String qry = "select bookedDate from appointment_booked";

       st = con.createStatement();
       rs = st.executeQuery(qry);

       PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();   
       JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
       ArrayList < Dates > list = new ArrayList < Dates > ();
       Map < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
       Dates sPojo = null;
       while (rs.next()) {
         sPojo = new Dates();

         sPojo.setDates(rs.getString("bookedDate"));
         list.add(sPojo);

       }
       System.out.println(list);

       jObj.put("dates", list);
       out.print(jObj); 

       System.out.println(jObj.toString());

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

}
```

**web.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>databaseJson</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>dating</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dating</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.dating</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dating</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dating</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Something I notice that looks strange: `maxDate: new Date(2014, 1, 28)` would lead me to believe that the datepicker wouldn't allow any dates to be selected after 1/28/2014.

Answer (score 0):

You have async request `$.ajax`, so `success` function is executed after datepicker is activated. You have to move its initialization of datepicker inside `success` function.

Comment: I thought the same, and you still may be right, but he says all dates are "unselectable".  I would think if that were the problem, then all would be selectable (the opposite).

Comment: @ViktorKukurba how would I go ahead to do that? Do I move the whole datepicker code into the success function?

Comment: Yes, try to move whole datepicker code into the success .